# How long would a Tower of Hanoi That has 64 discs take to solve recursively? C++

Tags: c++

I was looking at a recursive tower of Hanoi program where the function is called 2^n-1 times. My roommate asked me how long it would take to do a tower of 64. I honestly didn't know the answer so I'm hoping someone could help me out here, because I'm interested in the answer, instead of just waiting it out.

Also what would the Big-O notation be?

This is the code I was looking at:

```
void towerOfHanoi(int n, char from_rod, char to_rod, char aux_rod) 
{ 
    if (n == 1) 
    { 
        printf("\n Move disk 1 from rod %c to rod %c", from_rod, to_rod); 
        return; 
    } 
    towerOfHanoi(n-1, from_rod, aux_rod, to_rod); 
    printf("\n Move disk %d from rod %c to rod %c", n, from_rod, to_rod); 
    towerOfHanoi(n-1, aux_rod, to_rod, from_rod); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int n = 4; // Number of disks 
    towerOfHanoi(n, 'A', 'C', 'B');  // A, B and C are names of rods 
    return 0; 
}
```

got the code from GeeksforGeeks.org

Comment: _"instead of just waiting it out."_ Wait! What do you mean? That code consumes a close to infinite time?

Comment: If you mean actual real execution time, that depends on your system and should be measured by you. Nobody else can answer that for you

Comment: You should've looked at Wikipedia first, they explain this puzzle pretty well, especially 64-disc variant: *"According to the legend, when the last move of the puzzle is completed, the world will end."*

Comment: Run with a bunch of lower values for `n`, count the time the application needs in each case and devide that value by `2^(n-1)`, do it until you have enough data to estimate the growth rate of the time value for any `n`, insert `64` for `n`, done.

Comment: Also, it's interesting to note that the thing that's most important in answering this, is "How fast can your output display a line of text". That is _by far_ the slowest part of this.

Comment: @MooingDuck now let's do an exercise in metaphysics. Let's say, we omit the output, and will let the program to move the discs without outputting he moves. (We also assume optimizers don't figure it out and generate the code as written). Will the word end when the move is completed? In other words, "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?"

Comment: I found this interesting: https://hanoi.aimary.com/index_en.php it says `Approx. 584,942,417,355 years` for 64 disks assuming each move is a second.

Comment: You know how many times the function is called (2^64 - 1), so estimate how long each function call takes and multiply. Even if you under-estimate a bit (a microsecond?), you'll get an impressively large run time.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you know that a  tower of height `n` needs 2<sup>n-1</sup> calls, which all take about the same time.

So, time it for some not too big `n`, and set it in relation to the `n` you want.

Waiting for a tower of height 64 to be solved takes a bit too long to measure directly.

Regarding big-Oh, you know the step-count, so just remove constant factors and slow-growing terms.

Answer (score 1):

According to the origins of the game, it will take exactly until the end of the Universe we live in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi

> The puzzle was invented by the French mathematician Édouard Lucas in
>   1883. There is a story about an Indian temple in Kashi Vishwanath which contains a large room with three time-worn posts in it,
>   surrounded by 64 golden disks. Brahmin priests, acting out the command
>   of an ancient prophecy, have been moving these disks in accordance
>   with the immutable rules of Brahma since that time. The puzzle is
>   therefore also known as the Tower of Brahma puzzle. According to the
>   legend, when the last move of the puzzle is completed, the world will
>   end.

Answer (score 0):

"How long would this take to solve" is not a useful question; it entirely depends on the processing power of the system on which the code is compiled and run.

"What is the Big-O for a recursive implementation of the Towers of Hanoi" is absolutely solvable.  You will find when you do the calculation that it works out to be O(2^n) where n is the number of disks that you have.

You can find a very nice discussion of calculating Big O for ToH here:  [Discussion/proof](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~stejada/csci101/slides/2012/TowerHanoi.pdf)